Status Failed On, 403 Forbidden
I have a problem with this program, I used Spark Streaming to fetch posts from Twitter, but it cannot fetch posts and this error appears. This error appears when executing.
Error fetching tweets: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

"I used Spark Streaming to fetch posts from Twitter" Fetching posts via the X API requires one of the paid for access tiers.

Well if I use the (basic) x API v2 I can extract data through spark streaming from twitter?

I believe that you are trying to post to a v1.1 endpoint which does not support what you are trying to do. Try using a v2 endpoint. It could also be that you need a paid account to perform what you want to.
This is also a duplicate of:

403 Forbidden 453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints only
Twitter API access denied for posting a simple tweet
Twitter APIs Error Python: You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only

